# How to change background-image using input range?

Tags: html, ios, slider

I am making a small webapp for iOS just for my private needs and need some help with js.
Basically, what I need is a slider (similar to input type="range", but working on iOS <5), which controls the background of a div. In other words, each out of *n* backgrounds should be associated with a particular range on the input slider scale. Since I have only a very basic knowledge in javascript, writing a custom thing from scratch is out of the question. Maybe somebody can point at an existing solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use slider from Jquery Mobile library ( http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/slider/ ) for basic slider functionality and then change background with a range. For example:

```
// if backgrounds are equally spread on the slider then you can just 
// divide slider value to the number of backgrounds and round the results

var range = Math.round(your_range_from_slider / number_of_backgrounds);

// then change background to the one you need. For example 
// in you named backgrounds background_1.jpg, background_2.jpg, etc. 
// And element to which you want to set it have id="bg"

$("#bg").css("background-color", "background_" + range + ".jpg");
```

To learn more about JQuery syntax use http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page (to catch slider changes you will probably need to use change() event http://api.jquery.com/change/).